# End If in Access VBA giving me fits

Tags: vba, ms-access

I keep getting an error in this code saying "End If without Block If".  I've looked at it and can't see the problem, printed it out and connected all the If statements to their joining End If, and everything looks right.

Is something else throwing e off, like that With/End With block?

```
Private Sub cmd__Import_Eligibility_Click()


   ' Requires reference to Microsoft Office 11.0 Object Library.

   Dim fDialog As FileDialog
   Dim varFile As Variant
   Dim filelen As Integer
   Dim filename As String
   Dim tblname As String


   ' Set up the File Dialog.
   Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    fDialog.InitialFileName = "oo*.*"
   With fDialog


      ' Set the title of the dialog box.
      .Title = "Please select a file"

      ' Clear out the current filters, and add our own.
      .Filters.Clear

      .Filters.Add "Excel Spreadsheets", "*.xls*"
      .Filters.Add "Comma Separated", "*.CSV"
      .Filters.Add "All Files", "*.*"

      ' Show the dialog box. If the .Show method returns True, the
      ' user picked at least one file. If the .Show method returns
      ' False, the user clicked Cancel.
      If .Show = True Then

         'Loop through each file selected and add it to our list box.
         varFile = fDialog.SelectedItems(1)
         If Right(varFile, 4) = ".xls" Or Right(varFile, 5) = ".xlsx" Then


            'get only file name
            For a = Len(varFile) To 1 Step -1
                If Mid(varFile, 1) = "\" Then
                    filelen = a
                End If
            Exit For
            filename = Right(varFile, filelen)
            tblname = Left(filename, InStr(filename, ".") - 1)
            DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, tblname, filename, True
         End If 'ERRORS OUT ON THIS LINE ==========================
      Else
         MsgBox "You clicked Cancel in the file dialog box."
      End If
   End With

End Sub
```

Comment: your `Exit For` should be inside the IF statement under `filelen = a` and you should put `Next a` in its place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[As Scott posted as a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42074666/end-if-in-access-vba-giving-me-fits#comment71320829_42074666), your `For...Next` loop construct is malformed:

> ```
> For a = Len(varFile) To 1 Step -1
>     If Mid(varFile, 1) = "\" Then
>         filelen = a
>     End If
> Exit For
> ```

There's no such thing as a `For...Exit For` loop. You mean to do this:

```
For a = Len(varFile) To 1 Step -1
    If Mid(varFile, 1) = "\" Then
        filelen = a
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Otherwise the compiler is seeing [roughly] this:

```
 If [bool-expression] Then

    For [for-loop-setup]
        If [bool-expression] Then
            [instructions]
        End If
        Exit For
        [instructions]
 End If '<~ expecting "Next" before that "End If" token.
```

---

Running an auto-indenter would have made this problem obvious, I think. I happen to manage an open-source project that ported the popular *Smart Indenter* VBE add-in to .NET, so that it can run in 64-bit environments. See [rubberduckvba.com](http://rubberduckvba.com) for all the features.